# solution for org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)

Tags: java, json, hibernate, rest, resteasy

I know there are a lot of simiar errors already out there - and believe me, I tried most - but I simply can't fix this on my side. Generally I am using tapestry and resteasy to provide a REST service. Hibernate is my persistance framework. I have one Java object "Obj1" and another Java object "User". A user can own some Obj1's, so I have the following mapping for obj1 in the User:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner")
private Set<obj1> obj1s;
```

And on the other side (in Obj1):

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "owner", referencedColumnName = "guid")
private User owner;
```

So the user owns some Obj1's, while the obj1 is aware of it's owner. This gives me a exception

```
 org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: RESTEASY003770: Response is committed, can't handle exception
 <<omitted>>
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)
```

I found [this website](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492342/how-avoid-infinite-loop-during-json-serialization-in-java) and thought I was save...I tried doing the @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference thing on both sides (I even flipped them to see if I just annotated the wrong side with @JsonManagedReference) but still the same exception. I also found the

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="guid")
```

which I added to both sides ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065002/jackson-serialization-of-entities-with-birectional-relationships-avoiding-cyc)) but still nothing (guid is a property on both objects). I then found [this](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/138)  and added

```
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
```

to the collection-property but still with the same effect. Of course the most obvious thing would have been to use `@JsonIgnore`, found on the first link and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281541/org-codehaus-jackson-map-jsonmappingexception-infinite-recursion-stackoverflow), but this didn't work either. Now I am thinking that the issue might be somewhere else, maybe my dependencies are not correct... However, I was using the `com.fasterxml.jackson`-import (as this was suggested in some posts). The relevant section of my pom is:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jsapi</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tynamo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tapestry-resteasy</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

So, can anybody give me another hint or what I can still try to do? Of course, I could implement another object just for returing them via REST service and don't mix it with my objects for persistance. But I would definitely know how I can fix this issue...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason was that the import was wrong. It should have been

```
org.codehaus.jackson
```